# Eggplant - how to store dynamic values into excel cells

Tags: automation, eggplant

Here's sample code:

```
set myExcelDB to {type:"excel", file:ResourcePath(testRunFilePath), name:"TestRun" ,writable: Yes} 
put the records of myExcelDB into allTestRunRecords

repeat with each item of allTestRunRecords


put 1 into counter
put counter into currentRow.passed //why is this counter number not updated into my excel file?

end repeat
```

I had the counter values stored into the currentRow.passed field from the run window but the excel is not updated. Am I missing something?
I wanted to store to the current row's "Passed" column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it by using put first record of xxx

```
set myExcelDB to {type:"excel", file:ResourcePath(testRunFilePath), name:"TestRun" ,writable: Yes} 
put the records of myExcelDB into allTestRunRecords

repeat with each item of allTestRunRecords

put the first record of myExcelDB where ("ID") is it.ID into currentRow
put counter into currentRow.passed 

end repeat
```